# Countering a question closure by moderators

Tags: support, closed-questions, moderators

Is there a feature, or any scope for such a feature, where by a question closed by moderators can be counter-argued and re-opened?

Comment: You should link to the question you worry about so others might see it and vote accordingly if they agree, but I doubt that we would choose to overrule it, as our mods usually make really good decisions.

Comment: [This](http://serverfault.com/questions/347797/advice-guides-for-building-and-expandable-virtual-environment) is likely to be the closed question that caused this. Bear in mind, howerver, that none of the "voted-to-closers" were mods, just high-rep users with the ability for "vote-to-close" (also 3k rep).

Comment: You should post in the meta website with details of the question asking why a question was closed and/or asking why it should not have been. If people with enough reputation agree that the question should not have been closed, or if you can edit it so that it no longer deserves to be closed, then people will vote to re-open a question.

Comment: Also, as the commentor says, you need someone that has the time to spent analysing your needs rather than getting a couple of pointers from people on a web site.

Comment: @tombull89 Thanks for that info, I thought it was Mods only, cheers :)

Comment: @Rob Moir, Thanks for your input Rob. I am disappointed the question was closed for the reason given. For many questions asked on the StackExchange sites, there is no definitive right or wrong answer, and multiple ways to achieve the desired results, so a dead pan factual answer can't be given. I don't think closing a question because it will cause debate or solicit opinions is OK. I want the opinions of people who have been in the same situation as me, that is some of the greatest knowledge I could receive. [Closed question for reference: http://tinyurl.com/7vmw6fj]

Comment: Javano - the whole point of the main stack exchange sites, at the very least, is that they're supposed to deal with clearly defined, factual questions, and that questions that devolve into opinions and debate are **not** ok. That's part of the "constitution", if you like, of Server Fault, Stack Overflow and Super User. There is a place for those kind of questions, I agree, but that place *isn't here*.

Comment: Now if you wanted to argue that we sometimes apply that rule too rigidly then I might agree, and if you wanted to show how that had happened here then people would consider your point. But simply saying opinions should be allowed here because you want them isn't going to get you very far, I'm afraid. (see http://serverfault.com/faq#dontask )

Comment: I understand, thanks Rob.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you have enough rep, you can just vote to reopen. It needs 5 votes again to be  successful.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Ah I see, so presumably I don't have enough rep as I don't see such an option available to me?

Comment: You need 3000 rep, see the [faq] for more details.